# Iterating using each.do shows elements outside table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying show the user a table.  Problem which I'm facing is the fact that besides outputting what I need in the table, they are also outputted outside it.

https://gist.github.com/maimutza/28dda9cb1055d13e9439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= p.shipments.each do |s| %>`

I guess you should remove the = sign

`<% p.shipments.each do |s| %>`